# How to add a UIView in scrollViewDidScroll and enable it to scroll till the end?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am adding a `UIView` to the end of my `UIScrollView` as follows -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        UIView *paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight + 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
        [paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [self.containerScrollView addSubview:paintView];
    }
}
```

This added the view at the end, but I am not able to scroll that view. How do I enable scrolling to the newly added view as well?

Comment: You have to adjust the scrollview's contentSize with the newly added view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set scrollview's contentInset

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,extensionHeight,0);
```

but you probably don't wanna add subview in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` ,because this function would be invoked many times, your subview would be created many times.
If you have to add subview in it, I suggest you create a property paintView, and check if it is nil, if it is, create it, if not, just don't do anything

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,extensionHeight,0);
        if (!_paintView) {
            _paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight + 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
            [_paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
            [self.containerScrollView addSubview:_paintView];
        }

    }
}
```